Every A and B - singular or plural

Every mother and father wants their child to succeed.

My grammar book and every other source I've found says wants is correct because a subject with every is always singular.
However, my English teacher at school says every A and B is an exception because the subject is two people, the mother and the father. By her logic, it should be want. Is she wrong?
+

Every parent wants their child to succeed.

Can this be used as an alternative to the first sentence? My teacher says parent makes the sentence inappropriate because parent means mother and father - so it should be used as parents. But I think she's wrong. Please help.

Try googling "every parent wants" and "parents want"  and judge for yourself whether the former is wrong.  (It's not) as for "every mother and father" the verb that follows is singular e.g "Every boy and girl deserves to be loved"

Consider OP's first sentence;-


Every mother and father wants their child to succeed.



Ref. textbook.com website https://testbook.com/question-answer/choose-proper-verb-that-agrees-with-the-subject--6152cd5781e237247d374f74#:~:text=Grammar%20rule%3A%20If%20a%20subject,and%20each%20girl%20has%20come.
• Grammar rule: If a subject is modified by the words "each" or "every" that subject is singular and therefore will take a singular verb because Whenever we use Every or each before a noun, it means we are referring the noun individually.
• Example: Each boy and each girl has come.
• In this sentence, the Subject is 'Every boy and every girl'. Although this Subject contains two nouns and they are connected by the conjunction 'and', we have to use only a singular verb 'is', because the subject implies every one of all the students.
Thus, 'is' will be used in the blank.
Therefore, the correct answer is: 'Each boy and each girl is going to take part in the play.

The sentence -  "Every mother and father wants their child to succeed" - is correct.
Now let's consider the second sentence;-

2.Every parent wants their child to succeed.
BBC world service site
https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv266.shtml#:~:text=Every%2C%20like%20each%2C%20is%20always,the%20school%20is%20tuned%20regularly.
Every, like each, is always used with a singular noun form and therefore with a singular verb form in English because we are counting the things or people that we are talking about separately one by one: Every child in the class plays a musical instrument. Every instrument belonging to the school is tuned regularly.

The sentence - "Every parent (not parents) wants their child to succeed." - is correct.
The sentence below also conveys the same meaning:
All parents want their child to succeed.
